# How to highlight custom keywords in Quarto docs code chunks?

Tags: sql, r, syntax-highlighting, quarto

I'm writing a brief Quarto document where I explain some SQL clauses/keywords. I'd like to have all of those clauses to be highlighted in my code chunks, but not all of them are supported by default syntax highlighting. Is there a way to add custom keywords to syntax highlighting settings?

For example, I wrote the following code chunks:

```sql
SELECT col_name(s)
FROM tbl_name
LIMIT n OFFSET m

-- Syntax supported by MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQLite
-- LIMIT = number of rows to retrieve
-- OFFSET = starting row (optional)
```

```sql
SELECT TOP n col_name(s)
FROM tbl_name

-- Syntax supported by SQL Server and MS Access
```

And i got the following outputs in my rendered document:

[image]
[image]

I want both `OFFSET` and `TOP` to be highlighted in orange, like `SELECT`, `FROM` etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several SQL highlight variants, you can get a list of those with `quarto pandoc --list-highlight-languages` and switching from `sql` to `sqlpostgresql` will get you highlighted `OFFSET`.

It's surprisingly easy to customize any of the existing highlights, https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting points you to KDE-style XML syntax definition files, https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/tree/master/data/syntax .
Pick `sql.xml` (or any other )  as a base and add additional keywords:

```xml
...
    <list name="keywords">
      <item>OFFSET</item>
      <item>TOP</item>
...
```

I also changed the name attribute (`<language name="SQL_CUSTOM" ...` and saved it next to Quarto qmd as `sql_custom.xml`, having all files in a working directory, Quarto / Pandoc picked up updated definition file once it was added to `syntax-definitions` list.

Sample qmd:

````yaml
---
title: "custom syntax hl"
format: html
theme: solar
syntax-definitions: 
  - sql_custom.xml
editor: source
---

### sql

``` sql
SELECT col_name(s) FROM tbl_name LIMIT n OFFSET m
SELECT TOP n col_name(s) FROM tbl_name
```

### sqlpostgresql knows about `OFFSET`

``` sqlpostgresql
SELECT col_name(s) FROM tbl_name LIMIT n OFFSET m
SELECT TOP n col_name(s) FROM tbl_name
```

### sql_custom knows about `OFFSET` & `TOP`

``` sql_custom
SELECT col_name(s) FROM tbl_name LIMIT n OFFSET m
SELECT TOP n col_name(s) FROM tbl_name
```
````

And rendered result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I just finished editing the .xml file and now syntax highlighting works as I intended.