# rmarkdown read code from file and display with highlight

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have two RMarkdown files. `main.Rmd` which is the main file which is rendered as well as `example.Rmd` which holds a longer example and is used elsewhere (hence it lives in its own document).

I want to include `example.Rmd` in the `main.Rmd` file with code highlighting of its RMarkdown code but the code of `example.Rmd` does not need to be executed, as if I set `eval=FALSE` and copied all code into the chunk by hand.

An example MWE is

`main.Rmd`

````
---
title: This is main.rmd
output: html_document
---

```{r}
# attempt that doesnt work
cat(readLines("example.Rmd"), sep = "\n")
```
````

and in `example.Rmd`

````
---
title: This is example.rmd
output: html_document
---

```{r}
# code that is not executed but shown in main.Rmd
data <- ...
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `eval=FALSE` in the *example.Rmd* file and then include it in *main.Rmd* using `child` chunk option.

**example.Rmd**

````
---
title: This is example.Rmd
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
```

```{r}
# This is from example.Rmd
x <- rnorm(10) 
y <- rnorm(10)

lm(y ~ x)
```


```{r}
# some comments
print("This is from example.Rmd")
```
````

**main.Rmd**

````
---
title: This is main.Rmd
output: 
  html_document:  
    highlight: haddock
---

```{r example, child="example.Rmd"}
```
````

---

[image: code chunk included from another file with syntax highlighting]

---

## Edit

**To show full source-code of the Rmarkdown file**, one possible option could be reading that Rmd file and then `cat` it with chunk option `comment=""`.

Now about the syntax highlighting; there's a chunk option `class.output` with which it is possible to specify a language name for which pandoc supports syntax highlighting.

You can get the list of language names for which pandoc has syntax highlighting support by running the following,

```
pandoc --list-highlight-languages
```

(Note, if you don't have pandoc installed separately, you can also use the pandoc installed with Rstudio itself. Run `rmarkdown::pandoc_exec()` to get the pandoc executable path)

Now, the file we are trying to include actually contains not just R code, but also markdown and yaml syntaxes. So it's a kind of mixed thing and pandoc has no syntax highlighting support out of the box for this. Still I have chosen `c` as syntax highlighting language just to show the possibility. (Also tried `r`, but syntax-highlighting is not so distinctive)

````
---
title: This is main.Rmd
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: tango
---

## Rmarkdown

```{r example, echo=FALSE, class.output="c", comment=""}
cat(readLines("example.Rmd"), sep = "\n")
```
````

---

[image: included contents of rmd file with possible custom syntax highlighting]

---

But still if you want a specific syntax-highlighting for Rmarkdown, you can actually create one. [See here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#syntax-highlighting) from the pandoc documentation itself and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74170297/10858321) on SO about this.

Comment: Is there a way to display the full source code of example.Rmd, highlighted as (R)markdown code?