# Rmarkdown code chunk format for BibTeX entry

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I have a quarto markdown document (`test.qmd`). It contains a toggle button named `BibTeX` which expands into a specified $\BibTeX$ entry when expanded.

The `test.qmd` file reprex is as follows:

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
---

<!-- BibTeX -->
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#test2022paper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2022paper">
  BibTeX
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="test2022paper">
  <br>
  <div class="card card-body">
```{r, eval=FALSE}
@misc{test2022paper,
    title        = {
        A test' paper
    },
    author       = {Test authora, Test authorb},
    year         = 2022,
    eprint       = {arXiv:test}
}
```
  </div>
</div>
````

The issue is that the BibTeX entry is formatted as an `R` code chunk, which causes strange highlighting since the `test'` apostrophe is interpreted as the start of an `R` string, not a literal BibTeX entry text. See the image below, for the knitted output:

[image: sample output from knitted qmd]

Is there a way to display this BibTeX entry code chunk using `bib` file syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You can simply use `bibtex` as code chunk header to get BibTeX syntax highlighting.

Also since `bibtex` is the first code chunk in this MWE, you may want to specify `knitr` as engine, otherwise Quarto will try to render this document using `jupyter`.

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
engine: knitr
---

<!-- BibTeX -->
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#test2022paper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2022paper">
  BibTeX
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="test2022paper">
  <br>
  <div class="card card-body">
  
```{bibtex}

@misc{test2022paper,
    title        = {
        A test' paper
    },
    author       = {Test authora, Test authorb},
    year         = 2022,
    eprint       = {arXiv:test}
}
```
  </div>
</div>
````

### Option 2

Alternatively, if for some reason you want to use r-code chunk, but still want to get `bibtex` syntax highlighting, a possible way would be writing that bib as output and specifying `sourceCode bibtex` as output class.

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
---

<!-- BibTeX -->
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#test2022paper" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="test2022paper">
  BibTeX
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="test2022paper">
  <br>
  <div class="card card-body">
  
```{r}
#| echo: false
#| class-output: "sourceCode bibtex"

bib <- 
"@misc{test2022paper,
    title        = {
        A test' paper
    },
    author       = {Test authora, Test authorb},
    year         = 2022,
    eprint       = {arXiv:test}
}"

cat(bib, sep = "\n")
```
  </div>
</div>
````

---

[image: bibtex syntax highlighting]

---

Comment: Thanks so much! I used the first option, and it worked as intended. I had tried changing the code format to `bibtex`, but it kept knitting using `jupyter`, so changing to `knitr` as you suggested fixed it. Very cool! I'll accept your answer once the system allows me to.

Comment: Also - do you know where to find an **exhaustive** list of all supported languages for `qmd` code chunks (particularly for syntax highlighting). I had also tried `{bib}`, instead of `{bibtex}` which did not work, so having such a list would help avoid this issue as well.

Comment: @user4687531, see the edit section of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74233766/10858321

Comment: Thanks - I will remember to use `pandoc --list-highlight-languages` to check for syntax highlighting support.