# What is the correct way to insert and format non-executable code in Quarto?

Tags: quarto

What is the correct way of integrating arbitrary code in Quarto? In my case, I have an Overpass [API/Overpass QL example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) for extracting [OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/) data.

Is there a way to integrate code cells as non-executable code chunks or are code cells generally reserved for executable code, meaning that another formatting has to be selected for non-executable code?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT w/ Some Sugestions from @Fuhrmanator**

If I am understanding correctly, you are looking for a way to have code inside the Quarto document that is not executed / not run. If that is correct, there is a fairly simple solution for this: using code chunk options allow you to customize the behavior of code in every chunk or at the document level. Or you can include code via a "default" language flag.

For an overview of this topic, see [this part](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html) of the Quarto documentation.

At the beginning of each code chunk you are able to see options that effects that chunk visibility and execution. This is only applicable to the languages that Quarto can actually run. Take the below R chunk:

````
```r
#| eval: true # Do evaluate this chunk
#| echo: true # Do show this chunk in the final rendered document
#| output: true # Do show the output / results of this chunk in the rendered document

print("Dont run this code")
```
````

You can also include code in a stylized code block but it is not execute or ran, via normally markdown syntax. This can be helpful for code that cannot be executed in Quarto. Information on this can be found in [this section](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/markdown-basics.html#source-code) of the above documentation. Format non-evaluated code blocks with "default" where the language name would normally go.

````
```default
This is pseduo code
  that is placed within a code block but not run {
    return test  
Arbitrary code that is styled like code but will not run
  }
```
````

See @Fuhrmanator's comment for a possible way to get syntax highlighting for your chosen language.

Comment: Code fences are basic markdown: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/markdown-basics.html#source-code and a feature of pandoc (via Quarto). However, `overpassql` doesn't appear to be one of the 140 languages supported (syntax highlighting via skylighting). I found a KDE config at https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/blob/master/data/syntax/overpassql.xml and maybe you can make it work by putting it in the Quarto project and following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74170297/1168342

Comment: Thank you very much @Quinton.Quagliano. That helps very much and I will try to implement your suggestions.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: Thanks as well. I will try to set up a version that includes code highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

To show the code, but not execute, try the [Fenced Echo](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#fenced-echo).

[image]

Another approach to Unexectuted Blocks is the two curly braces around the language

[image]

Each will show the code block in the output document, but will not return the computation.